# Online booking software that allows restrictions on who can book appointments

Tags: web-apps, booking

I am in need of some advise.  I have been asked to setup an online booking system for an organization, and make it as simple as possible for them, while keeping these mandates:

1. only allow 'active' members to book appointments
2. Make it as simple as possible
3. Trying to keep people from having to login
4. allow for multiple payment methods like CC, Zelle & Venmo
5. Make sure that members who book online have signed liability waivers
6. Requiring people to pay in full before booking appointment

Now I have researched a few online booking platforms that are very inexpensive to free, that could work, but what I am having a hard time with is how to satisfy #1, while also satisfying #3 & #2.

So, my question to you is, does anyone know if such a system exists, and if so, could you please recommend it?

I have played with 3 options:

1. Setting up a booking-like site, using our membership management platform, which would make it foolproof for managing 'active' members, by deactivating login when members are in-active.
2. Setting up a separate online booking platform, and restricting it to public access, and putting it on a page, to restrict it via our membership management login.  Again, making it easy to manage credentials of who can access it, and
3. Using an online booking software that allows us to disable public signup, and manually adding/removing members.

I'm also open to any other ideas.

I really appreciate any and all help/advise that you can offer me.